# Maven versioning best practices

Tags: maven, versioning

What is the best way to change version of Maven project, to release this version and then return back to `*-SNAPSHOT` development.

Currently I'm doing following:

- retrieve current version (most likely with `SNAPSHOT`) from `pom.xml`
- increment version (`mvn -DnewVersion=<something> versions:set`), respecting rules described in the question [Maven artifact version for patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352326/maven-artifact-version-for-patches)
- `mvn:install` to sent to repo
- renaming version once again adding `SNAPSHOT` postfix.
- committing changes (using some version control system)

I have a strong feeling I'm doing something wrong and/or inefficient.

Comment: Generally nighty build having next-release-number-SNAPSHOT. So while releasing just remove -SNAPSHOT & release it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should use the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) to release your artifacts. Than automatically all your versions will be incremented by the release-plugin. The exception might be if you are going from 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT .
The timeline for developing with Maven is:

```
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
1.0.0
1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
1.0.1
1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
1.0.2
..
```

To go for the step from a SNAPSHOT to a release version you should use the maven release plugin you can release an artifact simply by using:

First step:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

The final step:

```
mvn release:perform
```

If you would like to accept the defaults you can simply add -B like:

```
mvn -B release:prepare
```

or you can combine those steps into a single one:

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform
```

The above can also be used from within a CI solution.

Using mvn install is only intended to install the artifacts into your local repository. If you are working with a real one like a repository manager (which i can recommend) you have to use:

```
mvn deploy
```

One requirement for using the release plugin is to configure the scm area in your pom (i hope you are using a version control?).

Comment: You may even omit the z position since e.g. 1.1 and 1.1.0 are equal. This is what I do and all maven plugins do. Moreover, a sole `release:peform` will fail because you did not provide `-DscmUrl=...`.

Comment: @Michael-O why are you specifying the SCM URL on the command line?  I suspect khmarbaise has provided it via the POM setting <scm><developerConnection>

Comment: @earcam, because the the plugin needs to know from there the release has to be built. The scm element contains not trunk in the default checkout.

Comment: Hi @Michael-O, you probably should be using .../trunk in the developerConnection see http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html and furthermore it's specifying trunk here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html - I'm using Git so not really an issue.  The whole release:prepare/release:perform works for me without specifying any further parameters

Comment: Re-read my first comment, I crearly indicated why and when you need to provide the SCM URL.

Comment: @Michael-O a bit late but still - please re-read my first comment too, we have numerous projects working fine simply using the scm definition and all the documentation backs that up.  If you're going to refute this, please cite some evidence.

Comment: Please recite the prominent part of the comment. I cannot really track what you want. If you are referring to the scmUrl. You have to supply that uf you perform first prepare and then perform in two separate steps.

Comment: @Michael-O, quote: "release:peform will fail because you did not provide -DscmUrl=..." - It will not if you specify all pertinent information in the SCM tags of the POM.  I issue `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` several times a fortnight without any further parameters.  Anyway believe what you will,  it was a minor correction that you seem hellbent of refusing, so be it.  Go well, in peace.

Comment: @earcam, well I haven't used those goals seperately for years. Always in tandem and they worked fine.

Comment: Bump. release:prepare actually adds an scm path in the TAG when it is committed. When performing release:perform, the latest tag will be built which magically has the scm path set. That is why you don't have to specify any path in your trunk project.

Comment: Can you confirm that the _timeline for developing_ is from `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0.0` and not from `1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0.0`?

Comment: I can confirm that. If you like to use `1.0-SNAPSHOT` than the release would be `1.0`...and not `1.0.0`...

Comment: Best practices? Consider : https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html too

Answer (score 5):

If you want more control over the release phase, the maven-release-plugin (mrp) will not help you much.

In that case I have [modified versions-maven-plugin](https://github.com/petr-ujezdsky/versions-maven-plugin) to be able to **increment version and also to add / remove SNAPSHOT suffix**.

Thanks to these new features you are able to write script that do the same thing as mrp, but you have full control over each step.

For example, mrp commits changed version *before* it actually tries to build it. If the build fails, you have to revert that commit or, in case of SVN, you have to do another revert-commit.

> Note: I am not the original author of the increment function. I have adopted it
>   from autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin, as stated on github page.

Comment: I have created a pull request on official `versions-maven-plugin`
 github page, hopefully they integrate it
https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/pull/23

Comment: What if I don't want maven screwing around with SCM?  For example, with GitHub actions I can fire off some CI with the TAG action but this directly conflicts with mavens release process...

Comment: Well, a lot has changed in the last 5 years. If they did not update the plugin to be more usable (however they didn't even bother with my pull-request above), I would consider using different method. Do not know which one though.

Comment: I ended up asking [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926797/maven-release-without-tagging-or-compiling/61927016#61927016) question about this as I was unable to find a suitable solution.  Turns out it can be done with the version plugin.

Comment: My solution above also uses `versions-maven-plugin`. It just adds another goals to be even more flexible. Though it is a bit outdated now I presume.