# How can I tell maven to release as different scm user

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Today I'[ve been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554688/maven-versioning-best-practices/9554758) about maven release plugin which is recommended tool for deploying releases to maven depo.

This knowledge brings to life some new crucial questions. Don't get me wrong, I'm thoroughly reading documentation and heavily experimenting (as much as it possible to experiment with production release code) with settings, but nevertheless failing to succeed.

So, the question is -  how can I tell `mvn release:prepare` to commit all that needed to be committed under different user.

Here is my config:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <username>releasebot</username>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Everything works pretty well - I'm asked to enter releasebot's password three times as expected, build is successful, but nevertheless, as I can see, from `git log` all these commits belong to my user, not the releasebot.

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to the docs, you've setup the username correctly: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#username

I recommend you to check the build logs if the git commands are being run correctly by the plugin. If the 'git ....' command doesn't contain the username parameter, then it's a maven-release-plugin fault and you should report a bug.

If the 'git ....' command contains the username parameter, you can try running the same  command in the terminal yourself. If you get the same result running directly, then it's a git problem.

Hope it helps!