# Adding an autoincrementing number to Maven <finalname>

Tags: java, maven

I am trying with the different options `Maven` provides, but I'm not able to find out any way to add an autoincrementing number.

Example:

- Build 1 : MyProj_1.jar
- Build 2 : MyProj_2.jar
- Build 3 : MyProj_3.jar
- Build 4 : MyProj_4.jar

Comment: But why would build 1 be different than build 2, unless some code has changed?  How would your auto-incrementer know about that?  There are plugins which use timestamps or SCM revision number, or a Maven property.

Comment: I just wonder: Why are you trying to build your own "versioning" on top of the Maven version system?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `maven-release-plugin` or `maven-build-helper` plugin. 
As shown in answers of this question. [Maven Pom.xml Auto Increment Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498136/maven-pom-xml-auto-increment-version)

```
$ mvn release:prepare
$ mvn release:perform
```

or using `maven-build-helper`
define following properties

```
parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion
parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion
parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion
```

Then run

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
```

The source: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/increment-versions-maven-build-helper-versions-plugin/

Comment: The Article helped me to get what I was looking for.Thanks @Lakshitha.