# Maven Release Without Tagging or Compiling

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface

I am trying to use maven to build a JNI project and I am running into some difficulty creating a GA release.  The project's native code needs to be compiled on at least 3 systems (Linux, OSX, Windows) due to the native code requirements.  I would also like GitHub Actions to produce a release build when I create a tag on GitHub.  Because of this, I am facing a number of issues with the maven release plugin.  It seems like maven's release process involves compiling and testing the code as well as screwing around with SCM before I can create a GA version and release.  This simply isn't possible for this JNI project.  I have already gone down the cross compiler route with Ant and I would really like to move away from that for any number of reasons, mostly Apple related.  I also thought about releasing each JNI target individually, but I would really like to bundle the native code inside of the JAR and things start getting complicated when I need to share a .m2 folder across different build environments.  Is it possible to release a maven project without all the compiling, testing and SCM nonsense? Maybe a different 3rd party plugin?  Is there a better way I should be doing this?  For reference, the pom can be found [here](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/maven/pom.xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use the release plugin, I had a lot more success with the [maven version plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

All the maven release plugin is doing is taking the version off the snapshot, creating a new commit and then upping the version to a new incremented SNAPSHOT. You can mimic this process without maven needing to know anything about your SCM using versions.

One way to do it is to not `SNAPSHOTS` and instead build with the git short hash as part of the version:

So while developing, the version looks pretty normal

```
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
```

The do a "release" build based on a tag. My flow was

- commit and push
- build - `mvn clean install`, results in `my-app-1.1.0.jar`
- deploy to a test env and run regression tests, if they succeed, we tag the commit with a "passed_tests" tag
- CI fires on tags that match "passed_tests" - this needed to be the same commit that resulted in the jar under test

  - runs `mvn -f ./pom.xml versions:set -DnewVersion=${gitProps['git.build.version']}_${gitProps['git.commit.id.abbrev']}`
    On the disk, our maven version is now:

```
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-abcdef</version>
```

- then runs `mvn deploy`. This is the artifact that gets deployed to the repo and now we have a jar file (or whatever) that has a version matching the git commit.

You could use the same process for all your target architectures.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This seems much more direct. I will give it a go.